# What does "human corroborators" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In the 1950s the United States government made contact with a race of
>   technologically advanced beings known as the Ghin. The Ghin leader, a
>   brilliant scientist named Cronos, had come to earth seeking a cure for
>   a deadly plague threatening to annihilate his race. Cronos believed
>   the cure to the plague could be found within human DNA, which was
>   remarkably similar to that of the Ghin.
>
> Embroiled in a deadly cold war with the USSR, the United States
>   government agreed to provide Cronos asylum and, more importantly,
>   access to US citizens as test subjects in exchange for Ghin
>   technology. With the bargain struck, a group of high-powered
>   individuals known as the Majestic 12 initiated a secret government
>   program. The project, codenamed Aquarius, saw the creation of several
>   underground facilities classi ed far beyond top secret. For over  fty
>   years, Cronos conducted his gruesome experiments on an unsuspecting
>   population with the aid of those who were entrusted to protect them.
>
> With the fall of the Soviet Union and the end of the cold war,
>   relations between the Ghin and the US began to deteriorate. Only
>   Cronos’ threat of exposing the Faustian deal kept the US government
>   continually supplying test subjects.
>
> Less than twenty-four hours ago, several test subjects managed to
>   escape the Subterra Bravo facility. Their actions led to a complete
>   breakdown in relations between the **human corroborators** and Cronos’
>   minions. Having planned for this eventuality, the US government has
>   enacted Omega Protocol . . .

Source: [Level 7 [Omega Protocol] boardgame manual](http://files.privateerpress.com/level7/docs/LEVEL_7_OmegaProtocol_Rulebook.pdf)

I looked up the word *corroborate* but I can't grasp the relation between its meaning "to confirm/support a theory/finding" and these "human corroborators" from the text. What are they supposed to confirm?

Answer (score 2):

You're right, "corroborate" doesn't make sense here. I think the author meant to use the word "collaborators", instead.

[From Wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/collaborator)

> collaborator (plural collaborators)
>
> 1. A person who works with others towards a common goal.
>
>    A person who cooperates traitorously with an enemy.

In this context I think it would be the second meaning, as the US is cooperating with aliens which are harming its citizens.